# infopath form with the dropdown values based on the current user

Tags: infopath

I have 2 lists in the same site. One is configuration list with the data like below image and another list with the InfoPath form.InfoPath form dropdown values need to fill with the logged-in user related departments.

configuration list(multi user, string field types) is like:-[image]

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath will allow you to get the Username. You could create a Rule with a "Username" conditional to setup your list values.

Comment: My list user field is a multi-user field. According to your condition :- domain\user1;domain\user2 = Username will not work.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath forms are not supporting the filter the data by using the multi-user field. The alternative solution is Jqaury:- But we have 2 problems.

1. Jquery will execute before InfoPath form load. :- Jquey
   **setTimeout** is the solution.
2. InfoPath form partial postback will replace Jquery modifications:- So needs to check and refresh the dropdown control values frequently.

**Jquery Code:-**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(sample, 7000);
});

function sample() {
var select =  $('#DDLControlID')[0];


if(select.length>1) //check dropdown is available or not
{

if(select.length>100) //my requirement is 100 length. Control is identified with all fields/Partial postback replaced the my jquery changes 
{
 GetListDataAndSetDDL();
setTimeout(sample, 9000); // Call function again 
}
else
{
setTimeout(sample, 9000); // Call function again
}

}
else
{

setTimeout(sample, 3000); // Call function again

}

}

function  GetListDataAndSetDDL()
{
 var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
 var listname = "ListName";  
 var currentUserId=_spPageContextInfo.userId;
 var url = siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$select=ID,Title,MUserFieldName/ID&$filter=substringof('"+currentUserId+"',MUserFieldName/ID)&$expand=MUserFieldName/ID";    
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: "GET",
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: function (data) {

        var items = data.d.results;      
     var select =  $('#DDLControlID')[0];

        for(var i = select.length-1; i > 0;i--) {       

             var itmExist=0;
             for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++)
             {   
                 if(items[j].Title==select.options[i].text)
                  {
                     itmExist=1; 
                  }                
             }
          if(itmExist==0)
          { 
            $("#DDLControlID option[value='" + select.options[i].value + "']").remove();          
          }         
        }       
     },
     error: function (data) 
            {  
            alert("error");     
            }
 });
} 

</script>
```